# Turning a boolean into a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean, session-variables

Any ideas how I can turn "edible" in the code into a session to display as a label on a different page?

The label will display a message like "yes can eat"

```
public int totalCalories()
        {
            return grams * calsPerGram;
        }
        public string getFruitInfo()
        {
            string s;
            if (edible == true)
            {
                s = fName + " is good and it has " + totalCalories() +
 "calories";
            }
            else
            {
                s = "Hands off! Not edible";
                //edible = Sesion ["ediblesesion"] as bool;
                // Session ["ediblesession"] = edible;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already know the answer. Just use your commented code

Comment: Also, if you just want to pass Data to another page, you can use POST and GET.

Comment: cheers guys was not working properly so i commented it out, but will keep trying.

Comment: You can't use "as bool" as Boolean is not nullable. That's the issue you were having probably

Comment: Thank you Haedrian,  How would i need to get round this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You already have the code for setting the session variable in the comment inside the `if` statement:

```
Session["ediblesession"] = edible;
```

However, you probably want to set the session variable *outside* the `if` statement, so that it gets a value even if the boolean value is `true`.

When you want to read the value back in the other page, you will get the boolean value boxed in an object, so you would need to cast it back to a boolean value:

```
edible = (bool)Session["ediblesession"];
```

Be careful with the spelling. If you try to read a session variable with the name `"ediblesesion"` (as in the code in your comment), you won't get the variable that you stored as `"ediblesession"`, and the compiler can't tell you that you made a typo as it's not an identifier.

If you want to read the value, but might come to the page without having set the value first, you would need to check if it exists:

```
object value = Session["ediblesession"];
if (value != null) {
  edible = (bool)value;
} else {
  edible = false; // or whatever you want to do if there is no value
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the `as` operator on value types, such as `bool`; therefore this line `edible = Session["ediblesession"] as bool;` is not allowed. If `bool` was nullable, then that is a different story.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: You are so right. Thanks for the correction. I removed that example, leaving only the cast that I already added. :)

Comment: With newer Versions you can use: `bool edible= Session["ediblesession"] as bool? ?? false;`

Answer (score 4):

Setting:

```
this.Session["Edible"] = myBoolean;
```

Getting:

```
myBoolean = (bool) this.Session["Edible"];
```

Comment: would i need to do this on the same page ?

Comment: No. Session lasts as long as it doesn't time out (which you can set in your config file - which is in hours). You can use Viewstate in a similar method if you only want it for the same page.

Comment: Set it in one page. Read (get) it from the other.

Comment: @Haedrian: The session timeout is in minutes, not hours. `<sessionState timeout="20" />` means 20 minutes, not 20 hours. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry - I meant that its generally set in the period of hours. Not something which is likely to expire (because you'd kick the user out)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool? edible;
object object_edible = Session["session_edible"];
if (object_edible != null)
    edible = object_edible  as bool?;
else
    edible = false;
```

'bool' is a non-nullable value type in c#, bool? is a nullable type